# .NET TDD with a Database and ADO.NET Entity Framework - Integration Tests

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, tdd, linq-to-entities

I'm using ADO.NET entity framework, and am using an AdventureWorks database attached to my local database server.  For unit testing, what approaches have people taken to work with a database?

Obviously, the database has to be in a pre-defined state of change so that the tests can have some isolation from each other...  so I need to be able to run through the inserts and updates, then rollback either between tests or after the batch of tests are done.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrote a blog post on this topic a few months ago: http://psandler.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/writing-unit-tests-for-data-access-code/

Comment: @Phil: Nice blog post.  In answer to your question `Do you really need to test your DAL discretely/directly?  If so, why?`, in my case I would say `Because I'm working with Entity Framework 4` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced a similar kind of situation.

**Storing data to DB and retaining them to previous state are not ideally unit tests. They are Integration test cases.**

In order to perform the integration tests (insert / update operations ) **without affecting the actual data** ,I would suggest the following

**1. Use different database(change the name of the actual DB) , and let the schema remain the same as the actual DB.**

**2. Point the unit tests to the newly created DB.**

**3. Now how do we create a new DB , for running the tests alone in an automated way ?**

**Ans : Have the SQL scripts listed in a batch file , such as this.(here i presume you are using SQL SERVER)**

E.g., sqlcmd  -i c:\data\runscripts\InventoryMonthEnd.sql

**Specify the batch file , which lodges this sql statement(s) to be executed in MSBuild process.**

Sample MSBuild Task .

```
<ItemGroup>
<StoredProcScripts Include="$(RelativeSPDir)/*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target>
<Exec Command="isql -E -n -b -d DBName -i %(StoredProcScripts.Identity)" Condition="'%(StoredProcScripts.Identity)' != ''"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have each test create it's own data and delete it when the test completes.  This way, the data a test requires and the test itself are kept closely together and can be maintained as one unit.  For data shared by a set of related tests (in the same *Test.cs file), I use `[TestInitialize] Start()` and `[TestCleanup] Finish()`.

I also have a utility program that re-creates an empty test database, as the unit test's cleanup code will not run if I'm debugging a test and terminate it in the debugger.  To re-create the database, I use EF 4's ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MbUnit which has a rollback attribute. This will make sure that all the changes made in the Test will be rolled back.

http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2006/07/25/MbUnit-database-testing_2C00_-and-thanks-to-Roy.aspx

Comment: Does the rollback attribute play nicely with Entity Framework?

Comment: EF has surprised me in a lot of ways, sometimes pleasantly but often not :-)  Still, certainly worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we solved it:

1. Use a Sandbox database in first place for development/testing
2. Create all necessary data in the tests
3. Delete all of the test data created by the tests after they pass/fail. Something like a `try...finally`

Answer (score 0):

A really effective way to manage data in your tests is to use a transaction.  A colleague introduced this to me and I later saw it used in a number of places (GOOS)

In C# if you use a TransactionScope and dont comit the transaction you have a really effective way of keeping things clean.